# Dualbooting Windows brings up Bitlocker randomly

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, bitlocker

So, I basically have my SSD split into 2 partitions (not counting the ones Windows makes during installation).

One is my personal Windows 10 Pro install with  Bitlocker disabled.
Second is my work Windows 10 Pro install with Bitlocker enabled.

What happens is basically every time I shutdown and power up my laptop (not reset, only shutdown) I will get Bitlocker key prompt instead of the "Choose your operating system" window. After smacking ESC and restarting the laptop, everything is back to normal. It is however increasingly annoying.

Is there something I can do to prevent Bitlocker recovery from showing up?

Comment: BitLocker requires the BitLocker Recovery whenever it determines a configuration change.